# Given $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ , define $f^2(x)=f\big(f(x)\big)$ which of the following are true?

Tags: calculus

Given $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ , define $f^2(x)=f\big(f(x)\big)$ which of the following are true?

(a) If $f$ is strictly monotone, then $f^2$ is strictly increasing.

(b) If $f^2(x)=-x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is injective.

(c) There does not exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f^2(x)=-x$

---

(a)I get that it is true.

I am not sure about the others.can anyone explain please.

Comment: Is there a missing 'if' in (b)? If (a) is true, then you can answer (c) (is $x \mapsto -x$ strictly increasing?).

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: Note that (b) is true because the premise is false.

Answer (score 4):

(b), (c) are also true

$\forall x_1,x_2$, if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $f^2(x_1)=f^2(x_2)$, so $-x_1=-x_2$, that is $x_1=x_2$, so $f$ is injective

If $f$  continuous, and $f$ is injective, then $f$ is strictly monotone, so $f^2$ is strictly increasing. But $-x$ is strictly decreasing, so (c) is correct.